How to create spl-token not 2022, using @solana/spl-token-metadata?
Is posibble create spl-token not 2022, using @solana/spl-token-metadata?
If possible please help me how to create that

You can see my answers in this thread: How to add metadata on SPL Token.
I hope this helps!

With @solana/spl-token-metadata, you can only add metadata to the Token Extensions (previously token 2022) program using the metadata pointer extension.
For spl-token program, you can use a library like Metaplex to incorporate Token Metadata.
Here's how you can do it using umi and mpl-token-metadata
Install required dependencies
npm install \
  @metaplex-foundation/umi \
  @metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults \
  @solana/web3.js \
  @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata \

Use the CreateAndMint function to create your token.
import {
    generateSigner,
    keypairIdentity,
    percentAmount,
    publicKey,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import {
    createAndMint,
    mplTokenMetadata,
    TokenStandard,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";


const umi = createUmi(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey("YOUR 8-BIT ARRAY SECRET KEY");

umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair)).use(mplTokenMetadata());

async function createAndMintFungible() {
    const mint = generateSigner(umi);

    // mint token
    let umiTX = await createAndMint(umi, {
        mint,
        authority: umi.identity,
        name: "Solana Gold",
        symbol: "GOLDSOL",
        uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/program-examples/new-examples/tokens/tokens/.assets/spl-token.json",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0),
        decimals: 6,
        amount: 1_000_000,
        tokenOwner: umi.identity.publicKey,
        isMutable: false,
        tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
    }).buildWithLatestBlockhash(umi);

    // sign with the mint address and provider
    let signedTX = await signTransaction(umiTX, [mint, umi.identity]);

    //convert to web3 js TX
    const web3TX = toWeb3JsTransaction(signedTX);
    let txHash = await conn.sendTransaction(web3TX);
    console.log(txHash);
}

createAndMintFungible().then().catch(console.error);

